# Can you determine if the user is logged onto Yammer with the embed script?

Tags: javascript, yammer

I need to determine if the user is logged into Yammer. We're trying to just use [Yammer's embed feed](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/embed). All this is is a script...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
```

... and a call to create the feed:

```
<script>
    yam.connect.embedFeed({
        container: '#container_id',
        network: 'networkname',
        config: {
            header: false
        }
    });
</script>
```

If the user is not logged in, I want to display the feed in a short container (to house just the login button). Once they log in, I want to expand the height of the container to better fit the feed.  So I would need to know:

1. Whether or not the user was logged in when they load the page.
2. If they're not initially logged in, trigger an event when the user does log in.

Is this possible with just the embed script/functionality, or would we need to use the JavaScript SDK as well?

Answer (score 0):

Embed doesn't have a way to directly report back to you about the user's login status. If the user isn't logged in, Embed will show a 'Login to Yammer' button. But Embed can handle SSO, so if you are using that in your organization and a lot of companies are now that the new simplified login with Office 365 has been rolled out, you just need to add `use_sso:true` in the config section.

To check the user's login status you'll need to use the JS SDK `yam.platform.getLoginStatus(callback, [forceRefresh])`

Answer (score 0):

Yammer Embed supports event listeners for certain events, one of which is when the user has logged in. To execute a function once the a user has logged in, have the following code after the `yam.connect` call.

```
yam.on('/embed/loggedIn', functionToCall);
```

Obtained from: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/feed-events